# Arduino micro window focus troubles

Tags: usb, arduino-micro, keyboard

I'm currently attempting to use an Arduino Micro as a ducky USB for penetration testing, and currently when I attempt to open a command prompt (or any other window) the window loses focus which prevents me from typing anything in it. Here's my sample code:

```cpp
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  delay(5000); //Delay for testing
  Keyboard.begin();

  Keyboard.write(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  delay(400);
  print(F("notepad"));
  enter();

  Keyboard.print("This is a test");
  enter();

  clear();
  Keyboard.end();
}

void print(const __FlashStringHelper *value) {
  Keyboard.print(value);
}

void clear() {
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
}

void enter() {
  Keyboard.write(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
}
void loop(){}
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this? I'm testing it on windows 10 home (not sure if that matters).